# Hide the "Structure" tab in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker

By default, my configuration of TeXmaker has a "Structure" tab (see below) which is the equivalent of the "Document Map" in Microsoft Word and shows a table of contents. I'm currently working on a small document, however, and would prefer to instead use the screen space to see more of the editor.

How can I turn off the visibility of the "Structure" window? (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The answer is simply to uncheck "Structure" in the "View" menu.